# Terraform - How to Refactor This Code Block with Nested for_each?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-sagemaker, amazon-sagemaker-studio

I have several images already saved to ECR and I want to make these ECR images custom Sagemaker Studio images. The catch is there are also several Sagemaker Studio Domains, so we have to create and attach these Studio images for each domain.

Here is what I have so far:

```
variable "sagemaker_domains" {
  type    = list(string)
  default = ["my_domain", "your_domain"]
}

custom_docker_images = {
    for domain in var.sagemaker_domains :
    domain => [
      {
        ecr_image_name    = "smstudio-custom"
        studio_image_name = "metaflowkernel"
        display_name      = "Metaflow Kernel"
      },
      {
        ecr_image_name    = "studio-sample-default"
        studio_image_name = "mambakernel"
        display_name      = "Mamba Kernel"
      }
    ]
  }

flat_images = flatten([
    for domain, images in local.custom_docker_images :
    [for image in images : merge({ domain = domain }, image)]
  ])

data "aws_ecr_image" "studio_custom_image" {
  for_each = {
    for image in local.flat_images :
    "${image.domain}-${image.studio_image_name}" => image
  }
  repository_name = each.value.ecr_image_name
  most_recent     = true
}

resource "aws_sagemaker_image" "sagemaker_custom_images" {
  for_each = {
    for image in local.flat_images :
    "${image.domain}-${image.studio_image_name}" => image
  }

  image_name   = "${each.value.studio_image_name}-${each.key}"
  display_name = "${each.value.display_name} - ${each.key}"
  role_arn     = ""
}

resource "aws_sagemaker_image_version" "sagemaker_custom_images" {
  for_each   = aws_sagemaker_image.sagemaker_custom_images
  image_name = each.value.id
  base_image = "${data.aws_caller_identity.current.account_id}.dkr.ecr.${data.aws_region.current.name}.amazonaws.com/${lookup(local.flat_images[each.key], "ecr_image_name")}:${data.aws_ecr_image.studio_custom_image[each.key].image_tags[0]}"
}
```

This is a bit confusing to me because I essentially first need to loop through the `custom_docker_images` local variable and create a Sagemaker custom image (and image version). One for each domain. Then I also need to pull in the corresponding most recent ECR image using `ecr_image_name`.

Error Message:

```
╷
│ Error: Invalid index
│ 
│   on main.tf line 47, in resource "aws_sagemaker_image_version" "sagemaker_custom_images":
│   47:   base_image = "${data.aws_caller_identity.current.account_id}.dkr.ecr.${data.aws_region.current.name}.amazonaws.com/${lookup(local.flat_images[each.key], "ecr_image_name")}:${data.aws_ecr_image.studio_custom_image[each.key].image_tags[0]}"
│     ├────────────────
│     │ each.key is "amp-mambakernel"
│     │ local.flat_images is tuple with 2 elements
│ 
│ The given key does not identify an element in this collection value: a number is required.
╵
╷
│ Error: Invalid index
│ 
│   on main.tf line 47, in resource "aws_sagemaker_image_version" "sagemaker_custom_images":
│   47:   base_image = "${data.aws_caller_identity.current.account_id}.dkr.ecr.${data.aws_region.current.name}.amazonaws.com/${lookup(local.flat_images[each.key], "ecr_image_name")}:${data.aws_ecr_image.studio_custom_image[each.key].image_tags[0]}"
│     ├────────────────
│     │ each.key is "amp-metaflowkernel"
│     │ local.flat_images is tuple with 2 elements
│ 
│ The given key does not identify an element in this collection value: a number is required.
```

Thanks for your guidance!

Comment: What's wrong with the current code? Any errors?

Comment: It's a bit messy and the indexing for the lookup is not correct - it's complaining about the indexing. I feel like there's a more elegant and cleaner way of doing this.

Comment: " it's complaining about the indexing" - what exactly is the full error msg?

Comment: Added error to OP

Comment: Your local, `flat_images`, is an array, not a map, so this is why your `flat_images[each.key]` is failing. You should make the local itself a map, so that they have the same key already, and you would spare some `for_each = { ... }` too, because `flat_images` would already be a map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you have is due to the fact that your local value `flat_images` is a list (thus indexed `0, 1, 2, ...`) while you are trying to retrieve the list's values with `each.key` which in your case is a string (`domain-studio_image_name`).

I would suggest you to turn `flat_images` into a map, so that you can retrieve its values using the key you choose.
For example, you could change `flat_images` like this:

```
flat_images = {
    for entry in flatten([
      for domain, images in local.custom_docker_images : [
        for image in images : {
          key   = "${domain}-${image.studio_image_name}"
          value = image
      }]
  ]) : entry.key => entry.value }
```

For reference, the output I get when I print the value of `flat_images` obtained as described above, using the input you provided in the question is:

```
{
  "my_domain-mambakernel" = {
    "display_name" = "Mamba Kernel"
    "ecr_image_name" = "studio-sample-default"
    "studio_image_name" = "mambakernel"
  }
  "my_domain-metaflowkernel" = {
    "display_name" = "Metaflow Kernel"
    "ecr_image_name" = "smstudio-custom"
    "studio_image_name" = "metaflowkernel"
  }
  "your_domain-mambakernel" = {
    "display_name" = "Mamba Kernel"
    "ecr_image_name" = "studio-sample-default"
    "studio_image_name" = "mambakernel"
  }
  "your_domain-metaflowkernel" = {
    "display_name" = "Metaflow Kernel"
    "ecr_image_name" = "smstudio-custom"
    "studio_image_name" = "metaflowkernel"
  }
}
```

This also allows you to change your `for_each` with `for_each = local.flat_images` which is arguably more readable.